# Solving a determinant equation for $x$ (matrix equation... inconsistent?)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to solve the following equation for $x$.

$|xI - A| = 0$ where $A = \begin{bmatrix}2& 5\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$

I want to add $A$ to the other side and and multiply $x$ through I but it seems like I get $x = $2, and also $x = 3$ at the same time... does this mean $x$ equal both values... or its inconsistent?  Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: no we havent reached that far, we are only studying determinants so far.

Comment: Think of what you mean by $|\dot{} |$. Determinant?

Comment: I thought those were absolute value signs, maybe they really do mean determinant though?

Comment: Absolute value would not make sense here.

Comment: thanks! I see how you got 7 and -2 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$ |xI-A| = \left| \begin{bmatrix} x-2 & -5 \\ -4 & x-3 \end{bmatrix} \right| = (x-2)(x-3)-20 = x^2-5x-14 = (x+2)(x-7).$$